# Unable to get environment variable while running test cases in Travis CI

Tags: python, travis-ci, pytest

I am trying to test my code with Travis CI, but I am unable to get the environment variable which I have specified in .travis.yml file

I have tried following in my local machine and it is giving me the value of environment variable

```
os.environ['test_env'] = 'test2019' 
print(os.getenv('test_env'))
```

I am using os.getenv('ENV_VAR') to get env variable in test case also

.travis.yml file

```
env:
  global:
    secure:<encrypted string>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here??

Comment: Please add a [mcve] or at least include the link to travis job/github repo.

Comment: @hoefling https://travis-ci.org/ashashingadia2996/test_python_20190520 link of travis job

Comment: Can't tell for sure without seeing the code (the link to github repo from travis job leads to 404), but since you're using `tox`, most probably you're not passing the env vars. `tox` environments don't inherit any env vars besides `PATH` - if you need to pass some env var, use `passenv` option; see [passing down environment variables](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/basic.html#passing-down-environment-variables) in the docs.

Comment: @hoefling, I've made my repository public, Can you please tell me after checking code?

Comment: @hoefling, Can you please tell me how can I specify variable which I have encrypted using travis with passenv

Comment: It's called `apikey`, right? Add a line `passenv = apikey` to the `[testenv]` section in the `tox.ini`.

Comment: @hoefling, Thank you so much for your help, It worked as expected :)

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @hoefling, At that time when you suggested adding a variable in tox.ini file, everything worked as expected but now i am getting "ERROR: InvocationError for command /home/travis/build/evm/evm/.tox/py27/bin/py.test --basetemp=/home/travis/build/evm/evm/.tox/py27/tmp (exited with code 5)" this error. Can you please tell me reason behind this?